# Prove that $S$ is submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let's consider in $\mathbb{R}^4$ the set
\begin{align}
S=\{(x,y,z,t) \in \mathbb{R}^4: &x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2=xyz,\\
&x^2y^2+2x^2z^2+3z^2y^2=xyzt\}.
\end{align}
I have to prove that $S$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$.

I think I need to show that the inclusion $i: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ is an embedding, so $i_{*|p}$ is injective and a homeomorphism with its image.
In order to show that $i_{*|p}$ is injective I have to check that the Jacobian of the function $F: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y,z,t) \mapsto (x^2y^2+y^2z^2+x^2z^2-xyz, x^2y^2+2x^2z^2+3z^2y^2-xyzt) $ has rank 2. Am I right?

Is there another way to solve it?

Comment: Your definition of $F$ is confusing.

Comment: @ArcticChar you're right, I edited. Have you any hints?

Comment: In general checking $F$ has rank 2 is the way to go. But this $F$ doesn't have rank 2 everywhere (e.g. at $(0,0,0,0)$ it has rank $0$).